# Missing postgis function "ST_Buffer(geography g1, float radius_of_buffer, text buffer_style_parameters)"

Tags: postgis

I have following st_buffer functions:

```
st_buffer(geography, double precision)
st_buffer(geometry, double precision, text)
st_buffer(text, double precision)
st_buffer(geometry, double precision, integer)
st_buffer(geometry, double precision)
```

Any suggestions? (I want to use endcap=flat.. on my geography) my postgis version is 2.2.1

The function that I aim for is on [postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) hence not on [postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html)

Comment: What makes you think that such exists? The documentation does not mention it http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html.

Comment: At http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html I found this.. Synopsis
geometry ST_Buffer(geometry g1, float radius_of_buffer);
geometry ST_Buffer(geometry g1, float radius_of_buffer, integer num_seg_quarter_circle);
geometry ST_Buffer(geometry g1, float radius_of_buffer, text buffer_style_parameters);
geography ST_Buffer(geography g1, float radius_of_buffer_in_meters);
geography ST_Buffer(geography g1, float radius_of_buffer, integer num_seg_quarter_circle);
geography ST_Buffer(geography g1, float radius_of_buffer, text buffer_style_parameters);

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it depends on outdated websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed postgres 9.6 and install postgis 2.3.3-1 and the function was there, simple as that :)

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the doc, the optional third parameter only applies to geometry. Not to geography.

```
The optional third parameter (currently only applies to geometry) can either specify number of segments [...]
```

http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html

Comment: What about: http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html.. Synopsis
geometry ST_Buffer(geometry g1, float radius_of_buffer);
geometry ST_Buffer(geometry g1, float radius_of_buffer, integer num_seg_quarter_circle);
geometry ST_Buffer(geometry g1, float radius_of_buffer, text buffer_style_parameters);
geography ST_Buffer(geography g1, float radius_of_buffer_in_meters);
geography ST_Buffer(geography g1, float radius_of_buffer, integer num_seg_quarter_circle);
geography ST_Buffer(geography g1, float radius_of_buffer, text buffer_style_parameters);

Comment: You are right that http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html is the official site. But even that site gives opposite information `The optional third parameter (currently only applies to geometry)`. Probably it is a very new feature. If if does not work with your PostGIS version you do not have it.